# how to save rdd to different S3 buckets simultaniously

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I want to know how to save the computed rdd to different locations.
Also extend the same for notifying without computation.

```
rdd = <do some action>
```

as I know `rdd.saveAstextFile("s3://<location1>")` will store to `location1`, 
but if I want to store to `location2` also how to do it? 
I am not sure whether `persist/cache` ( my understanding is it will `cache/persist` in master node) will work as `rdd` size is very big.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> my understanding is it will cache/persist in master node.

Where did you find this? This is not correct. As per the spark documentation below is the explanation.

> One of the most important capabilities in Spark is persisting (or caching) a dataset in memory across operations. When you persist an RDD, each node stores any partitions of it that it computes in memory and reuses them in other actions on that dataset (or datasets derived from it). This allows future actions to be much faster (often by more than 10x). Caching is a key tool for iterative algorithms and fast interactive use.

Also,

> The cache() method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY

i.e cache() is similar to persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY).
Follow this link to decide which storage level to use as per your requirement.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose

You can use below for saving at two location:

```
rdd.cache()
rdd.saveAstextFile("s3://<location1>")
rdd.saveAstextFile("s3://<location2>")
```

More details are here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence